# Error when trying to get image properties using HTTP reuest in parse

Tags: image, parse-platform, httprequest

I get error 141 saying object has no method "success' using the following code. I simply need to get the image properties from the url. Attched is the full error from Corona SDK.[image]

```
Parse.Cloud.define("changePhoto4", function(request, response) {
  var Image = require("parse-image");
  var baseurl = "http://files.parsetfss.com/7bdfab67-db97-4761-936f-be05679ca518/tfss-dc75c8e2-06b6-45fb-bfde-b2befb8ad84a-0.png";
  var params =  {
}
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
       url: baseurl,
    success: function(response) {
var image = new Image();
    return image.setData(response.buffer, {
      success: function() {
        response.success("Image is " + image.width() + "x" + image.height() + ".");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        response.error(image);
      }
    })
},
    }, 
    function (error) {
        console.error('Console Log response: ' + error.text);
        response.error('Request failed with response ' + error.text)
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe change the name of your function parameter in line `success: function (response)` so that it's clear which response variable you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("changePhoto3", function(request, response) {
  var baseurl = "http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3123/2341623661_7c99f48bbf_m.jpg";
  var Image = require("parse-image");
  var params =  {
}
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseurl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: params
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {

        var image = new Image();
    return image.setData(httpResponse.buffer, {
      success: function() {
        console.log("Image is " + image.width() + "x" + image.height() + ".");
               response.success(image.width()+"x" + image.height());
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // The image data was invalid.
      }
    })

    }, 
    function (error) {
        console.error('Console Log response: ' + error.text);
        response.error('Request failed with response ' + error.text)
    });
});
```